# One session per user (Node.js, Passport.js, Express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, passport.js

## 1. Current

passport.js - localStrategy 
express.js - express-session 
db - mysql 
user model - id, email, pw, ip

## 2. Question

I'd like to develop my auth module as one session per user.  
 
What I tried. 
1) npm module 
https://github.com/marcosun/one-session-per-user <- I tried this too, but it's not working.

2) ip check 
if ip exists in db, alert. 
but if user didn't logout, and just close tab or browser. 
It's hard to handle reset session data and user ip in db. 
 
so I tried to find detect tab close or browser close. 
I found ' onbeforeunload ', but it goes in refreshing page, not only close tab or browser 
 
What would be a best solution in my case...

Comment: The express session set a cookie to keep the session... So there is one session per user... I don't really understand your question... What's the issue clearly ?

Comment: @BENARDPatrick But I can have another login with same user account and another session stacks in database. I want to make if a user logged in the service, nobody can't login with the user account which is logged in.

Comment: Ok I understand. So, When your user is logging, just have to loop inside the session store to find if an existing session with this userId exists. Look at this : https://github.com/expressjs/session#storeallcallback

Comment: @BENARDPatrick Love you